# how can I copy the content of popup box in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to open a URL (of another domain) in a popup box and then want to copy the whole content of that web page's contents either into the clipboard or in a variable. So that I can use it in my web application.

My code is like

```
function openWin()
{
    myWindow=window.open("http://www.abcxyz.com","","width=400,height=200");

    //some code for copy content
    myWindow.close();
}
```

This function displays the webpage that i want to access. What I need is to copy that content.

NOTE:

- I can't use AJAX to copy the contents of the URL (it produces an error because of the same origin policy).
- I can't use cross domain AJAX: the web url replies only after authentication and cookies are stored in my browser, so the request must be initiated by the browser, not from any server.

Comment: You must go via a server, you can't do this on the client. If you could, it would make the web completely untrustworthy.

Comment: @RobG what is problem in that..
the content is now displayed in browser window and I want to copy that thing in my website using java script.

Comment: What do you mean with "content", the HTML markup? No, there is no way to access any cross-domain pages' contents on the client. If you want the other webpage appear in your app, you can use an iframe.

Comment: @Bergi yeah its normal text data in html tags, no images, no css...
One more problem is, I am not able to display it in Iframe. I tried a lot but its not showing in Iframe. I tried a lot..
Actually I am developing facebook application where I am using some facebook's own ajax call to retrieve data..
[link]http://andromeda.nitc.ac.in/~ritesh/fbpending/
here is my application, it's working but I want to make it more user friendly so for novice users..
please suggest me some Idea..

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try this:

```
function openWin(){
   m = window.open("some.url.here");
   m.addEventListener("load", function(){func(m);});
}

function func(v){
   var c = v.document.body.innerHTML;
   v.close();
}
```

Comment: its not working it gives an error like this...
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.OtherDomainWebSite.com/index.php?varible1=value?varible2=value from frame with URL http://www.mydomain.com/application/test.html Domains, protocols and ports must match.